# mod rewrite to 301 any index file to index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to redirect any index file that isn't index.php to that file. I'm doing this in the unlikely event that another type of index file is explicitly named in the URL. This hopefully should  prevent any 404 file not found errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profordable/index.php [L,R]
```

Comment: Working for me, can you check your error.log file and tell me what is the error.

Comment: This is not the right error line. Tail the log file and send your request again to spot the right line. May I also know what URL did you try to test this?

Comment: Not a problem take your time.

Comment: I'm using wamp, the address is localhost/website and the error line is:: [Wed Jul 17 16:04:18 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/aDomain/profordable/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: modrewrite wasn't on, so it is redirecting now, but to localhost instead of localhost/website, think this is the line that needs to be changed but don't know how:  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]

Comment: What exactly is `localhost/website` ? Is it a folder under DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: document root under wamp always resolved to c:/wamp/ or "localhost' but I need to resolve to c:/aDomain/profordable, or alias 'profordable' with address http://localhost/profordable/    can I add the 'profordable' folder name to the above line somehow?

Comment: can i just add the folder name 'profordable' here? because I think you're right on the money except without the folder name.

Comment: Yes I have added `profordable` folder in my latest edit. Please try it now.

Comment: If you want URL to change also you will need R flag also. Try: `RewriteRule ^ /profordable/index.php [L,R]` (latest edit)

Comment: you did it! you're awsome